# Swift Attributes - Deprecating by OS Version

Tags: swift, xcode, deprecated

So we have the ability in Swift to mark available by OS version and newer but I don't see an ability to mark something as unavailable by OS version and older.

For instance I can mark an extension as available in only watchOS 5.0 and newer by saying:

```
@available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *)
extension HKLiveWorkoutBuilder : HKLiveWorkoutBuilderProtocol{

}
```

But there is no way of marking an extension, class, function, etc... as unavailable, obsolete, or deprecated in a particular version and newer:

```
@available(watchOSApplicationExtension, introduced: 4.2, deprecated: 5.0)
extension HKLiveWorkoutBuilder : HKLiveWorkoutBuilderProtocol{

}
```

or

```
@available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, unavailable)
extension HKLiveWorkoutBuilder : HKLiveWorkoutBuilderProtocol{

}
```

There's no build warning or error from Xcode 10.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode 10 GM Seed recommendations are:

```
  if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
    update(<#T##userActivity: NSUserActivity##NSUserActivity#>)
  } else {
    ///your old action pre v5.0
  }
```

maybe that **#available** vs **@available** is the issue......shot in the dark.  *Still updating my new func signatures*

Comment: I don't think that would work since I'm trying to hide an entire class from newer OS version. #available only works with sections of code as opposed to @available which works on classes, methods, properties, etc...